# Displaying only the drop-down options which are relevant

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

Only those Drop Down Options which are relevant to me on a web-page should be visible to me. (Others should be hidden)

Example:

Instead of a drop-down which has options:

A
B
C
D
E
F

I want only below 2 options to be visible to me
A
C

This would save our time and less chances of selecting incorrect option since the drop-down currently has more than 10 options and only 3 options are relevant to my team.

Kindly Note: We are not allowed to change the source code of the page, so I am hoping this is possible via scripts(JS) which can be run on Grease/Tamper Monkey.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can disable all select-options except the relevant:

```
var opt = document.getElementById("yourSelectBoxId").getElementsByTagName("option");
for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
  if(! ['A','C'].includes(opt[i].value)) {
    //disable it:
    opt[i].disabled = true;
    //or remove it:
    //opt[i].parentNode.removeChild(opt[i]);
  }
}
```